# Is there a way to log the React component hierarchy to the console?

Tags: reactjs

I would like to log the React component hierarchy (not the DOM!) to the console so that I can see what components are in the tree during Jest tests, but have not come across any pre-built way to do this.

Is there an existing way to accomplish this, either via an official or 3rd party package?

Comment: React dev tool in browser?

Comment: How would that work with Jest tests?

Comment: Why do you need to see the component tree during Jest tests? Aren't you supposed to query element by doing `screen.getByRole()`, and test the behavior?

Comment: If you want to query a perticular tag on the screen, there's a browser plugin called `locatorJS`, comes pretty handy.